# How can I individuate the text that encloses some other text in a pattern and edit it with regex

Tags: swift, regex, string, nsstring

I'm learning about regex and I'm trying to create a program where a certain pattern is substituted.

Given the following string:
@@@hello@!

I want to recognise "@@@" and "@!" and substitute them with "*** and "*^". What's between these characters must remain as it is.

Now, I tried something like:

```swift
text.replacingOccurrences(of: #"(@@@)"#, with: "***", options: .regularExpression)
text.replacingOccurrences(of: #"(@!)"#, with: "*^", options: .regularExpression)
```

but if my string is:

> "@@@hello@! @@@hello@@@"

my output becomes:

> "***hello*^ ***hello***"

while the desired one should be:

> "***hello*^ @@@hello@@@"

In fact I only want the characters to be substituted when they follow the pattern:

> @@@ some text @!

I created a regex with the following pattern:
`#"(@@@)(?:\\.*?)(@!)"#`

but I'm not able to get the text and substitute it.
How can I individuate the text that encloses some other text in a pattern and edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```swift
text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: #"(?s)@@@(.*?)@!"#, with: "***$1*^", options: .regularExpression)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9my6m4/1). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - an inline "singleline" flag that makes `.` match any char
- `@@@` - left-hand delimiter
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` refers to this value): any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `@!` - right-hand delimiter.

Swift test:

```
let text = "@@@hello@! @@@hello@@@"
print(text.replacingOccurrences(of: #"(?s)@@@(.*?)@!"#, with: "***$1*^", options: .regularExpression))
// -> ***hello*^ @@@hello@@@
```

Comment: Woah thank you! These regular expressions are mind blowing! Do you have any suggestions on where I can learn more about them?

Comment: I will accept the answer in 9 minutes btw

Comment: @crost I can suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at. Besides, see [regex SO docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics).

Comment: Thank you! I will make sure to check everything!

Comment: @crost I also started to write some generalized posts about some regex topics [here](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/posts). Also planning some yt channel with some regex writing demos.

Comment: I followed you and I'll make sure to check your channel as well if you open it!

Comment: @crost Hi, I have started uploading some [regex videos on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw), feel free to check them out if you want to learn more about regex. As I am a novice in Youtubing, I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for remembering. I am following you asap! :)